Mail Merge messing decimal places
When using an Excel spreadsheet as input to Word Mail Merge feature, the decimal places get all messed up:

8,1 becomes 8,0999999999999996
7,0 becomes just 7

(commas are the decimal separator, and dot is the thousand separator)
Question: how to prevent this from happening again? It is tiresome to fix these errors manually!

Where are these numbers from? Are they the results of formulas. What is the formatting on these cells? Note that formatting numbers to display only one decimal value does not change the value in the cell, only what is displayed. Maybe convert the displayed value to text before doing the merge?

Have you done a search? And what did you attempt to do to solve the problem?

Does this answer your question? Microsoft mail merge incorrectly formatting numbers

8,1 becomes 8,0999999999999996 ... probably not ...  the cell value is probably 8,0999999999999996 and is being displayed as 8,1

It is tiresome to fix these errors ... those are not errors

Word pays no attention to the formatting of numbers in Excel.  You must do the formatting in Word using switches and pictures. http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501

@jsotola No, the cell value is 8,1 insted of 8,0999999999999996. I can guarantee that. And this little deduction is not intented, so it is an error.

Press Alt+F9 > Insert the field code \# 0.0 after the title of the merge field that needs to be limited 1 digit after the decimal point.

Press Alt+F9 to hide the merge field codes.


\#0.0 did result in "08" instead of "8,1". But \#0,0 did the trick.
